# If AWS EC2 is in STOPPED state, Will it be able to respond to any SQS message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs

Here EC2 AMI is already configured to respond to particular message.

Comment: In stopped state, EC2 instance basically shut down and will not be responding any of the operations because as its name says, it's stopped and it's not operating.

Comment: A stopped EC2 instance is a computer that has been turned off. It isn't "responding" to anything. Also, SQS does not push messages to EC2, ever. Your EC2 instance would have to be polling the SQS queue for new messages.

Comment: yes, my EC2 is polling the queue for new messages

Comment: How will it poll if it's stopped?

Comment: Please note that your EC2 instance does not 'respond' to messages. Instead, it 'polls' the queue to ask if there are any messages. Therefore, while the EC2 instance is Stopped, messages will be kept in the Amazon SQS queue for up to 14 days. If the EC2 instance later Starts, it can the process the messages that are in the SQS queue.

Answer (score 1):

No,

The role of an SQS consumer is to pull messages in the queue, if the application is installed in a non-running EC2, of course it cannot perform the reading of messages from the queue.